# Encryption and Decryption effect on performance Android

Tags: android, encryption, cryptography

I am planning to implement AES encryption and decryption in my app. Currently I have about few list items in Recycler View, where certain text items will be decrypted while displaying.Earlier I was showing directly as a plain text from DB, now I am storing the encrypted text in DB and while displaying decrypting it.

Will it effect the performance of the app, by multiple decryption while displaying items in RecyclerView. Will it consume CPU cycles and in turn eat battery ?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it will. Encryption eats CPU cycles and therefore battery. It depends on the CPU, the system and the implementation how much.

For small, displayable text I would not worry too much with regards to AES operations though. Latency may be affected, but the amount of CPU and therefore battery will be linear with the amount of ciphertext that has to be decrypted.

Make sure you only decrypt the data once, not on every repaint. Data decryption is normally not part of a GUI, but part of the business logic.

Comment: Thank you.. will make changes accordingly.